# When using `react-apollo` to bind component to a query, should I use the `<Query>` component or the `graphql()` function?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm confused about the best practice when building a new `react-apollo` app and trying to bind my components to a graphql query.

For example, I've seem some places in the `react-apollo` documentation which suggest I use `<Query>`:

```
const GET_ALL_DOGS = gql`
  query {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
      displayImage
    }
  }
`;

const Feed = () => (
  <Query query={GET_DOGS}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (error) return <Error />
      if (loading || !data) return <Fetching />;

      return <DogList dogs={data.dogs} />
    }}
  </Query>
)
```

Where as other places in the documentation suggest I use the `graphql()` function:

```
function TodoApp({ data: { todos } }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map(({ id, text }) => (
        <li key={id}>{text}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default graphql(gql`
  query TodoAppQuery {
    todos {
      id
      text
    }
  }
`)(TodoApp);
```

Looking at the examples and docs, it seems like `<Query>` represents a subset of `graphql()`, in which case it seems like you'd be better off using `graphql()` across the board, but I thought I heard that using `<Query>` was the preferred approach, and it appears to be used more often in the tutorial in the `react-apollo` documentation.

Any help for a newbie would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use either, it's a matter of preference. Using the graphql function was the standard before react-apollo 2.1 which still supports it by the way. Using `<Query>` was introduced in react-apollo 2.1 and I think personally it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Know the reasons behind both Render Props and Higher Order Components then choose what works best for you.

Rather than give you my opinion on which to use, I think it could be best for you and your continued learning to point out that these are two implementations using two very important React patterns: Render Props (or Function-as-Child-Components) and Higher Order Components (HOC). Apollo is allowing you to choose the one that works best for you. You should know both of them because you will run into both in many places.

The first example is of the Render Props implementation. It's new to Apollo. The second example is of the HOC implementation.

Apollo has a great blog post explaining why they implemented Render Props for Apollo Client on Medium. See https://blog.graph.cool/tutorial-render-props-in-react-apollo-2-1-199e9e2bd01e.

Google more. There is an ongoing debate as to which is better.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks @casey!

Answer (score 1):

React-apollo 2.1 has released new component Query and Mutation. From in my opinion it was huges improvement from Apollo team building the great GraphQL ecosystem in react-apollo module. For the best practice I think you should use the Query component because from now all frontend developers who used GraphQL client are using Query and Mutation component but it an option to know how to use graphql(). Kinda weird confused for the first time using graphql() in mutation.

Answer (score 1):

For smaller, simpler cases feel free to use both. There isn't much advantage to any of them. But I've used both in large scale, complex cases and I can tell you that the simplicity of `Query` and `Mutation` components will save you so much time and headache along the way.

Another downside of the `graphql()` is that it will more likely force you to create a parent component for your query component to take care of your variables (in most cases).

Also, I personally rather deal with props and elements, than to define everything in curly brackets and take care of nested objects and indentations. When the options and variables in graphql() grow, it can easily get out of hand :)